# puppet cannot find class from installed module apache

Tags: vagrant, puppet

This is probably just a basic question, but I can't find a solution. I set up an environment where I want to use the apache module given by puppetlabs.
My puppet version is 3.7.2
tree of my directory:

```
.
├── environments
│   └── test
│       ├── environment.conf
│       ├── manifests
│       │   └── site.pp
│       └── modules
│           ├── apache
│           │   └── manifests
│           │       ├── init.pp
│           │       └── vhost_basic.pp
│           └── update
│               └── manifests
│                   └── init.pp
└── Vagrantfile
```

my provisioner inside Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|  
  puppet.environment_path = "environments"  
  puppet.environment = "test"  
  puppet.options = ['--verbose']
end
```

my site.pp:

```
 Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }
 include update

 node 'localhost' {
   class { 'apache': }             # use apache module
   apache::vhost { 'example.com':  # define vhost resource
     port    => '80',
     docroot => '/var/www/html'
   }
 }
```

inside the apaches (directory) init.pp I only have `include apache`. And I installed the apache module via `puppet module install puppetlabs-apache`. And it's also stored in `home/user/.puppet/modules`. I also installed the module via sudo (since I read somewhere that it makes a difference..). But when I run `vagrant provision` it says me:

```
 ==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
 ==> default: Running Puppet with environment test...
 ==> default: Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class apache at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/environments/test/manifests/site.pp:16:3 on node localhost
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT:
the result of `puppet config print |grep path` is:

```
path = none  
environmentpath =   
basemodulepath = /home/user/.puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules  
modulepath = /home/user/.puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules  
factpath = /home/user/.puppet/var/lib/facter:/home/user/.puppet/var/facts
```

Comment: In Vagrantfile your machine has set hostname on "localhost" ?

Comment: which value do you have for `modulepath` in your `environment.conf` ?

Comment: @k0chan not it wasn't set but adding `config.vm.hostname = "localhost"` gives the same result

Comment: @FrédéricHenri my `environment.conf` looks like this: `modulepath = ./modules:$basemodulepath:/etc/puppet/modules`, there is also the module apache. If I remove this file, it has the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `environment.conf` is not correct, as you installed the modules locally they will be shared in your VM under the `/vagrant` directory so you should reference this instead. (they are shared in your `/etc/puppet` directory when you indicate the `puppet.modules` path in your puppet provisioner block)

However what I suggest is to add a simple shell provisioner which will install the modules for you (and manage the sudo part) - In your vagrantfile (before the puppet provisioner)

```
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "/path/to/script.sh"
```

In your `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

puppet module install puppetlabs-apache --version 1.10.0
```

This will install the modules in /etc/puppetlabs ... so you can reference this in your `environment.conf`

```
modulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:$basemodulepath
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for that. Didn't know that it searches for modules inside the vm.. But makes sense.. Your solution was close, it's not under `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/modules` inside the vm but under `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules`.